# How to bypass seccomp in linux

Tags: linux, security, exploit, seccomp

---

Even if a process uses seccomp and limited to exit, read and write, could I still do harm? And if I can, how is it possible to exploit a system like that?

Answer (score 1):

The exploitation of such a system depends on a variety of factors such as: it depends on how the rules for **seccomp** were written or it depends on whether there are other vulnerabilities in the program.
For example, using the *retf* instruction, you can switch from a 64bit system to 32bit, which allows you to perform different syscalls (32bit: https://www.informatik.htw-dresden.de/~beck/ASM/syscall_list.html, 64bit: http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/)
But a way to bypass the **seccomp**, I personally do not know.